# angular ui.router and linking to dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a backend rails app that produces and API for a front end ionic app to consume. I have the rails side (mostly) done, and am building the ionic app. I have experience working with angular, but not ionic.

Anyway, my question is I have a resource I'm receiving from the API. It's static, and the only actions available to it are `index` and `show`. I receieve the index action fine and can list them, but linking to the `show` pages results in a blank white screen. I put a couple `console.log` calls in the angular show controller to see if it's running at all, and it is, but it's not linking to the page. Here is the set up:

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

.state('app.search', {
    url: "/search",
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
      }
    }
  })

.state('app.gyms', {
    url: '/gyms',
    views: {
      'tab-gyms': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/gyms.html',
        controller: 'GymsIndexCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.gymShow', {
    url: "/gyms/:gymId",
    views: {
      'tab-gyms': {
        templates: "templates/gym.html",
        controller: 'GymsShowCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/search');
})
```

**controllers**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('GymsIndexCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Gyms) {
  $scope.gyms = Gyms.index(function(response) {
    console.log("from gyms");
    console.log(response);
  });
})

.controller('GymsShowCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Gyms) {
  $scope.gym = Gyms.query({id: $stateParams.id}, function(response) {
    // this is what's running, and it works
    console.log("running");
    console.log(response);
  });
})
```

**gyms.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Gyms">
  <ion-content>
    <h1 class="text-center">Gyms</h1>
    <hr class="generic">
    <div ng-repeat="gym in gyms">
        <div class="list card">
              <div class="item item-avatar">
                <h2 class="pull-left"><b>{{gym.name}}</b></h2>
                <p class="pull-lefft">{{gym.description}}</p>
              </div>

              <div class="item item-image">
                <img src="{{gym.images}}" style="min-height: 200px;">
              </div>

          <!-- where the linking is. I have tried routes like this, and the
          ui.router syntax of ui-sref="app.gymShow({gymId: gym.id})"
          neither produce and error, but neither work -->

              <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#/app/gyms/{{gym.id}}">
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
                {{gym.reviews_count}} reviews
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In the ionic scaffold example, it uses this

```
  .state('app.playlists', {
    url: "/playlists",
    views: {
      'tab-playlists': {
        templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
        controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
    views: {
      'tab-playlists': {
        templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

and I have tried to follow that exactly, but still not luck.

I have 2 questions. The first is how do I link to say `show` pages from an `index` action in ionic. And the second would be, can I use $routeProvider in Ionic? I know I should be able to, but I have not seen many resources showing that, so I do not want to cause too much overhead related to that just because I was having problems linking pages.

Any help pointing me in the right direction about either of those questions is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was incredibly dumb on my part. In this section

```
.state('app.gymShow', {
    url: "/gyms/:gymId",
    views: {
      'tab-gyms': {
        templates: "templates/gym.html",
        controller: 'GymsShowCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

was supposed to be changed to this

```
.state('app.gyms', {
    url: '/gyms',
    views: {
      'tab-gyms': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/gyms.html',
        controller: 'GymsIndexCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

dumb syntax error on my end